# Is territoriality only the domain of the male of a species?

Tags: sociality, territoriality

Is territoriality (recognizing a geographic location, and challenging another member of the same species and gender) only in the domain of the male of a species? Are there any species out there where the female of the species identifies, defines, and protects her territory? What about any species where territoriality is gender neutral (*tic* humans excluded!)?

I thought of bees, but that is a community affair - even if it is a matriarchial society.

Comment: From personal observation: house sparrows "stake a claim" at a bird feeder, and both males and females chase away competitors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely not.  In many spiders and insects, the female holds the territory.  Many spiders for instance have much larger females than males - in these species the female can be > 10x bigger than the male and the male may not even eat during its lifetime.

Ordinary garden [orb weaving spiders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orb-weaver_spider) are this sort of animal.  Only the females even spin webs.

Another example is the [Australian red back spider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redback_spider).

Quite often males are the 'disposable sex'.

Answer (score 2):

Both sexes of red squirrels defend exclusive year round territories.
See [Smith 1968](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/1948536) or [Steele 1998](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3504443).

Answer (score 0):

The elephant matriarch (in Africa) leads her followers where they go for food and water.